# How to convert tomcat 8.5 to TomEE installing the required libs?

Tags: tomcat, apache-tomee, java-ee-8

yes, I know, the answer would be "why don't you install TomEE directly?", but the only web server approved of the company is Tomcat 8.5 and I want to know if there is some way to convert my tomcat server to TomEE "manually" installing the required libs and dependencies or some plugin in the server. I have to migrate applications running in Liberty to Tomcat and the last one doesn't support thing like EJBs, JPA, JTA, JAX-RS etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TomEE offers a drop-in war archive, which can be used to enhance a Tomcat with the TomEE capabilities.

The TomEE documentation has some information about the [installation procdere](http://tomee.apache.org/master/docs/installation-drop-in-war.html) as well as about the [drawbacks](http://tomee.apache.org/master/docs/tomee-webapp.html) of such an approach.

However, the drop-in war approach is subject of removal in later versions of TomEE. The last [drop-in war releases](https://tomee.apache.org/download.html) are 7.1.4 and 7.0.9, which are EE7. If you want to have EE8, you are stuck with [8.0.6](https://tomee.apache.org/download-archive.html) as the drop-in war approach was dropped in later releases.

Regarding the Tomcat version:

- 8.0.x is build upon Tomcat 9.0.x
- 7.1.x is build upon Tomcat 8.5.x
- 7.0.x is build upon Tomcat 8.5.x

The TomEE drop-in war should match the related Tomcat version (as mentioned above), i.e. if you have a Tomcat 8.5.x in your company, you can only get EE7 capabilities from the drop-in war archive.